# Updating layer datasource in multiple map documents using ArcPy gives SyntaxError?

Tags: arcpy, layers, syntaxerror

I would like to update the data source of a specific layer in multiple map documents using ArcPy.

However, I'm getting a `<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: invalid syntax` error on `if lyr.datasetName == inputlayer` in the code below.

```
import arcpy, string, os
import arcpy.mapping as MAP

try:
    MXDList = string.split(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), ";") #ArcMap document(s)
    inputlayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # featureclass
    newwork = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) # Workspace

    for MXDPath in MXDList:
        MXD = MAP.MapDocument(MXDPath)
        for dataframe in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(MXD):
            lyrs = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(dataframe)  
            for lyr in lyrs:
                if lyr.datasetName == inputlayer
                    lyr.replaceDataSource(newwork, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", "Center")
    MXD.save()
```

What causes the SyntaxError here?

I was attempting to reference this forum [thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/40806-Replace-Data-Sources-from-shapefile-to-feature-dataset-feature-class-in-an-mxd-using).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a colon. `if lyr.datasetName == inputlayer:`

Also, the last line MXD.save() should be indented an additional 4 spaces.